# Can't gen Data with Fabrics FabricRecipeProvider

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I will auto gen Recipes with FabricRecipeProvider in Fabric 1.19.4 but if i run genData it will get me the error:

```
[main/ERROR] (FabricDataGenHelper) Failed to run data generation
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to run data generator from mod (jefs)
    at net.fabricmc.fabric.impl.datagen.FabricDataGenHelper.runInternal(FabricDataGenHelper.java:134) ~[fabric-data-generation-api-v1-11.3.6+5da15ca1f4.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.fabric.impl.datagen.FabricDataGenHelper.run(FabricDataGenHelper.java:86) ~[fabric-data-generation-api-v1-11.3.6+5da15ca1f4.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.Main.handler$zzc000$fabric-data-generation-api-v1$main(Main.java:535) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.server.Main.main(Main.java:120) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.game.minecraft.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:462) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.19.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.Knot.launch(Knot.java:74) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.19.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.loader.impl.launch.knot.KnotServer.main(KnotServer.java:23) ~[fabric-loader-0.14.19.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86) ~[dev-launch-injector-0.2.1+build.8.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate recipe jefs:aluminum_ingot
    at net.fabricmc.fabric.api.datagen.v1.provider.FabricRecipeProvider.lambda$run$1(FabricRecipeProvider.java:80) ~[fabric-data-generation-api-v1-11.3.6+5da15ca1f4.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.data.server.recipe.ShapedRecipeJsonBuilder.offerTo(ShapedRecipeJsonBuilder.java:114) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.data.server.recipe.RecipeProvider.offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(RecipeProvider.java:332) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.data.server.recipe.RecipeProvider.offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(RecipeProvider.java:315) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at de.rajala1404.justenoughfoodstuff.data.RecipeGeneratorInit.generate(RecipeGeneratorInit.java:50) ~[main/:?]
    at net.fabricmc.fabric.api.datagen.v1.provider.FabricRecipeProvider.run(FabricRecipeProvider.java:76) ~[fabric-data-generation-api-v1-11.3.6+5da15ca1f4.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.data.DataCache.run(DataCache.java:95) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.data.DataGenerator.method_46563(DataGenerator.java:49) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at net.minecraft.data.DataGenerator.run(DataGenerator.java:42) ~[minecraft-merged-project-root-1.19.4-net.fabricmc.yarn.1_19_4.1.19.4+build.2-v2.jar:?]
    at net.fabricmc.fabric.impl.datagen.FabricDataGenHelper.runInternal(FabricDataGenHelper.java:132) ~[fabric-data-generation-api-v1-11.3.6+5da15ca1f4.jar:?]
    ... 7 more

> Task :runDatagen FAILED
6 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 1 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runDatagen'.
> Process 'command 'D:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value -1
```

I think its a offerReversibleCompactingRecipes but i do not understand why this happend
TheCode:

```
        offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(exporter, RecipeCategory.BUILDING_BLOCKS, ItemInit.STEEL_INGOT, RecipeCategory.MISC,
                BlockInit.STEEL_BLOCK);
        offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(exporter, RecipeCategory.BUILDING_BLOCKS, ItemInit.KNIFE_STEEL_INGOT, RecipeCategory.MISC,
                BlockInit.KNIFE_STEEL_BLOCK);
        offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(exporter, RecipeCategory.BUILDING_BLOCKS, ItemInit.ALUMINUM_INGOT, RecipeCategory.MISC,
                BlockInit.ALUMINUM_BLOCK);
        offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(exporter, RecipeCategory.MISC, ItemInit.ALUMINUM_NUGGET, RecipeCategory.MISC,
                ItemInit.ALUMINUM_INGOT);
        offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(exporter, RecipeCategory.BUILDING_BLOCKS, ItemInit.BAUXITE, RecipeCategory.MISC,
                BlockInit.BAUXITE_BLOCK);
```

After i run the genData it generated not all files. it stop generating at

```
offerReversibleCompactingRecipes(exporter, RecipeCategory.MISC, ItemInit.ALUMINUM_NUGGET, RecipeCategory.MISC,
                ItemInit.ALUMINUM_INGOT);
```

Comment: I think there's a longer method signature that accepts (At the end I guess) a string, to provide a custom output path. You just have to put your mod_name:some_name_for_recipe

I'm using the ShapelessRecipeJsonBuilder and it works fine that way.

If that works, I'll post an answer.